# How to download videos from YouTube to Google Drive

Tags: youtube, google-drive, google-chrome

I am looking for a webapp which can download videos from YouTube to Google Drive. I am preferring pure webapp not browser extension based solutions, because primarily I will use that webapp in mobile chrome browser. There is one webapp https://www.seedr.cc, which is for torrent downloads. I am looking for same, in which I will put YouTube video URL or playlist URL and it will download whole content and push it to Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, under the current [Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms?archive=20191225), you are not supposed to download videos from YouTube. It is supposed to be a service where you merely view or listen to the content *on the website*. I quote from the Terms:

> The following restrictions apply to your use of the Service. You are not allowed to:
>
> 1. access, reproduce, download, distribute, transmit, broadcast, display, sell, license, alter, modify or otherwise use any part of the Service or any Content except: (a) as specifically permitted by the Service;  (b) with prior written permission from YouTube and, if applicable, the respective rights holders; or (c) as permitted by applicable law;
> 2. circumvent, disable, fraudulently engage with, or otherwise interfere with the Service (or attempt to do any of these things), including security-related features or features that: (a) prevent or restrict the copying or other use of Content; or (b) limit the use of the Service or Content;

Seeing as there is no download button on the website, the website clearly does not "permit" this by default, and I would consider such a feature a "restriction" on copying content.

Therefore, one should not download YouTube videos directly to Google Drive.

Generically, I would recommend using a sync client such as [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) or [InSync](https://www.insynchq.com/) in order to push files to your Google Drive storage.

Answer (score -1):

You can download Creative Commons licensed videos and upload them encrypted on Telegram with [PGPgram](https://github.com/tallero/pgpgram) (not a web app though).